# Remove CSs after click in jQuery

Tags: function, jquery

I have this structure:

```
$('.user_adr_edit div a').click(function(){
$(this).css('width', '210px');
});
```

It's working. But I want, when clicked again, remove `width:210px`

Must use `unbind`, `remove` or other solution?

Comment: Do you need to toggle width..?

Comment: Do you want to toggle functions? So 1. click: add width, 2. click: remove width, 3. click: add width and so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.user_adr_edit div a').click(function(){
   if($(this).css('width') != '210px'){
      $(this).css({'width':'210px'});
   }
   else{
      $(this).css({'width':'0px'});
   }
});
```

Comment: @zenith to be entirely honest I've never used toggle.

Comment: but yes toggle like in @GabyakaG.Pertioli answers looks a much nicer way of doing it

Comment: I wouldn't: toggle has been deprecated since 1.8 and was removed in 1.9: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

Comment: @cdmckay thanks for the info! Now I'm glad I never got into using it.

Comment: Also it is better to use `.css('width','')` to revert to its previous condition, instead of setting it to `0`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli yes that would... but with the `:` instead of the `,` =P

Comment: @vletech, yep.. have already edited it..

Answer (score 3):

You should use css rules to change css attributes

**CSS**

```
a.wide{
   width:210px;
}
```

and just add/remove the class

```
$('.user_adr_edit div a').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('wide');
});
```